# Prove that Euclidean, spherical, and hyperbolic 3-manifolds are THE only three-dimensional geometries that are both homogeneous and isotropic.

Tags: general-topology, 3d

The book Introduction to Topology by C. Adams and R. Franzosa says :

> There are only three three-dimensional geometries that are both homogeneous and isotropic: the Euclidean, spherical, and hyperbolic geometries.

It has been just written without giving even a little reason(s)/explanation, let alone a proof of it.

What is an easiest rigorous proof for the mentioned claim from the book?

EDIT - For the definitions of homogeneous and isotropic spaces, I quote it from the same book:

> To be isotropic means that at each point the geometry appears to be the same in all directions around the point. There is no preferred identifiable direction. This is a property that Euclidean 3-space $E^3$ has, for instance. However, if we form a geometry by taking $S^2 \times E$, for example, that geometry has different behavior in different directions.
>
> To be homogeneous means that locally the geometry of the space is the
> same. Given any two points in the space, there is an isometry (a distance-preserving homeomorphism) from a neighborhood of one point to a neighborhood of the other.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you define geometry, homogeneous and isotropic? Thanks.

Comment: @JohnMa - I edited. Actually I've studied them in cosmology as well, but they fortunately have the same definitions in maths and physics.

Comment: It seems that your question is answered [here](https://www.math.uni-tuebingen.de/user/loose/studium/Dissertationen/Diss.Konstantis.pdf). (See  in particular p.74)

Answer (score 5):

Given tangent 2-planes $P \subset T_p M, Q \subset T_q M$, there is an isometry $f$ taking $p$ to $q$; then using that $M$ is isotropic pick a local isometry taking $df_p(P^\perp)$ to $Q^\perp$; this takes $df_p(P)$ to $Q$. So we have a local isometry taking any tangent 2-plane to another. Thus the sectional curvature is constant. If $M$ is simply connected, it must be one of the three geometries you mention. However, $M$ needn't be simply connected; $M = \Bbb{RP}^n$ with the round metric is a homogeneous isotropic space, for instance. Maybe simply connected is demanded by your definition of 'geometry'.

Comment: This is a good answer but it seems like it is skipping some steps. Doesn't this (by defining inner products on the tangent spaces) a priori assume that the manifolds have a Riemannian metric/connection, when all one is given (seemingly) is that the manifolds are metrizable? Not even that they are smooth/differentiable?

Comment: @Chill2Macht You need a notion of tangent space to get a notion of direction to get a notion of isotropic.

Comment: That's actually a very interesting insight -- I need to remember it, I had not heard of or thought of it before. I hope that doesn't sound sarcastic, I do mean it.

Comment: Sure, thanks. It actually turns out to be a major sticking point in building a theory of topological manifolds that they don't have a good notion of tangent bundle.